# Error when I try to send email from one server to another on the same internal network

Tags: linux, postfix

I posted this question on a different forum but it was deemed to be off-topic.  I hope this time I have an appropriate forum.

We have two e-mail servers on the same internal network, for example 10.0.50.101 (Linux postfix) and .103 (Windows iMail). Both have public addresses and are functioning correctly, except when we try to send e-mail between the two. They always fail. Here is a log snippet from the Windows machine when we tried to send an email to the Pi.

```
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) R<xxx@mysite.com> - 1
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) [x] doing direct send mysite.com
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) Trying mysite.com (0)
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) [x] Connecting socket to service <SMTP> on host <mysite.com> using protocol <tcp>
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) [x] using source IP for myothersite.com [10.0.50.103]
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 220 mail.mysite.com ESMTP Postfix(Raspbian)
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) Connect mysite.com [10.0.50.101:25](1)
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) >EHLO myothersite.com
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 250-mail.mysite.com
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 250-PIPELINING
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 250-SIZE 10240000
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 250-VRFY
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 250-ETRN
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 250-STARTTLS
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 250-8BITMIME
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 250-DSN
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 250 CHUNKING
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) >MAIL FROM:<yyy@myothersite.com>SIZE=646
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 250 2.1.0 Ok
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) >RCPT To:<xxx@mysite.com>
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 550 5.7.23 <xxx@mysite.com>:
Recipient address rejected: Message rejected due to: SPF fail - not authorized. Please see http://www.openspf.net/Why?s=mfrom;id=yyy@myothersite.com;ip=10.0.50.103; r=<UNKNOWN>
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) Unexpected RCPT TO response from the SMTP server on mysite.com: 550 5.7.23 <xxx@mysite.com>: Recipient address rejected: Message rejected due to: SPF fail - not authorized. Please see http://www.openspf.net/Why?s=mfrom;id=yyy@myothersite.com;ip=10.0.50.103;r=<UNKNOWN>
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) >QUIT
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) 221 2.0.0 Bye
09:12 21:54 SMTP-(fecc01bb1000e5e9) [u] closing socket (u)
```

and another snippet from the Pi syslog file for about the same time.

```
Sep 12 21:54:43 email-2 dovecot: imap(xxx@mysite.com)<19089><GXUG9YboidFDK9hG>: Logged out in=877 out=11039 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Sep 12 21:54:45 email-2 dovecot: imap(xxx2@mysite.com)<19091><evQZ94bontFDK9hG>: Logged out in=388 out=2997 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
```

For the entries from the syslog, those may (??) be related to my laptop receiving mail from the server to see if the email was sent/processed.

And, trying to follow the URL in the error message, returns that the site is not available.

Thanks in advance for any ideas as to why intra-network mail transfers (port 25) are not working....RDK

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is related to the DNS record settings. The DNS text record that specifies the Sender Policy Framework (SPF) settings may contain information that conflicts with the way you send mail. See the text from your log:

```
Message rejected due to: SPF fail - not authorized.
```

Check the content of your DNS SPF record(s).

Your Windows server may not meet the criteria set out in the SPF record that describes which servers are authorized to send mail from the domain used for mail sent from Windows Server.

Proposal for procedure:

1. Go to the DNS server and temporarily delete the SPF record that is created for the mail domain related to Windows Server. Verify that the TXT/SPF record has expired and is not cached. The Postfix server must no longer use it for checking.
2. Try to send a message from the Windows Server to the Postfix and check the log.
3. If you succeed in sending the e-mail message, you have found the cause of the problem. Study the SPF settings and create a text DNS SPF record appropriate to your situation so that the Windows server meets the criteria listed in the record.

See e.g.:

- https://www.duocircle.com/content/spf-records/spf-record-example
- https://mailtrap.io/blog/spf-records-explained/

### A DNS record checking example

Let the Windows server mail domain be named, for example, mywinmail.net

The MX record check on Linux server:

```
dig -t MX mywinmail.net
```

The check of the TXT record(s):

```
dig -t TXT mywinmail.net
```

You must select the SPF type if there exist multiple TXT records:

```
dig -t TXT mywinmail.net | grep -i spf
```

Comment: Thanks, we will investigate this, sounds reasonable as the Windows Server mail setup is very old